# Adding SourceAccountID to AWS Config Aggregator Using the AWS-CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-config

I am currently trying to create an aggregator for all of the config rules I created in order for a client to have a centralized place to view all regions config metrics.

Here is my code to create the configAggregator:

```
            //adding role for configAggregator
            const configAggregatorRole = new iam.Role(this, 'configAggregatorRole' ,{
              assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('config.amazonaws.com')
            });

            configAggregatorRole.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AWSConfigRoleforOrganizations'));
            configAggregatorRole.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('ReadOnlyAccess'));


            //adding a content aggregator for managed config rules below
            const globalConfigAggregator = new config.CfnConfigurationAggregator(this, 'globalConfigAggregator',{
              configurationAggregatorName: 'globalConfigAggregator',
                AccountAggregationSourceProperty: {
                  accountIds : this.account 
            }
          });

    }
  }
```

I am currently trying to figure out what I should pass to specify that I want this account and x region to be the aggregated view of all the config rules in all the regions in that account. I am not sure how to do this. Thank you!